# How press "shift" + "command" + "3" simultaneously programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, nsevent

I am trying to capture a screenshot by posting this Keyboard event. I tried below way which doesn't work:

1]

```
CGEventRef event1, event2, event3, event4, event5, event6;
event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)56, true);
event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)55, true);
event3 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)85, true);//or 20
event4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)85, false);// or 20
event5 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)55, false);
event6 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)56, false);

CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event1);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event2);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event3);

CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event4);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event5);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event6);

CFRelease(event1);
CFRelease(event2);
CFRelease(event3);
CFRelease(event4);
CFRelease(event5);
CFRelease(event6);
```

2]

```
CGEventRef event7;
event7 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)85, true);//or 20
CGEventSetFlags(event7, kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
CGEventSetFlags(event7, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event7);
CFRelease(event7);
```

Both are not working. Suggest me any good option.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2625802/2648673

Comment: @MarekH thanks for the response but this is not sufficient for me

Comment: Your comment is unclear, have you tried it and it doesn't work or you can't write code? Maybe update question that you have tried it using NSEvent + getting CGEvent out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1] doesn't work because you don't set the event flags. 2] doesn't work because you don't post the key-up event and `CGEventSetFlags(event7, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);` replaces the `kCGEventFlagMaskShift` flag. Set both flags:

```
CGEventRef event7;
event7 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)85, true);//or 20
CGEventSetFlags(event7, kCGEventFlagMaskShift | kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event7);
CFRelease(event7);

event7 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)85, false);//or 20
CGEventSetFlags(event7, kCGEventFlagMaskShift | kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event7);
CFRelease(event7);
```